Issues with SharePoint Site Backup Using Microsoft Graph API in C#
I am working on a C# application to back up all files from the admin area of my SharePoint site using the Microsoft Graph API. I have multiple SharePoint project sites: some where the backup works successfully and others where the backup fails. Below are the details of my setup and the issues I'm encountering.
Environment:
Development Tool: Visual Studio Community
NuGet Packages: Microsoft.Graph, Azure.Identity
Authentication: ClientSecretCredential
Graph API Version: Using the latest version of Microsoft Graph API
Target Directory: Files are to be downloaded to D:\DownloadedFiles
The backup works fine for nearly 130 projects, but it seems it doesn't even recognize 200 other project sites. I have checked the site settings and configuration XML files for both a working and a non-working project site and found them to be structurally identical. Below is my anonymized C# code for backing up the sites.
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    private static string clientId = "anonymized";
    private static string tenantId = "anonymized";
    private static string clientSecret = "anonymized";
    private static string downloadPath = @"D:\DownloadedFiles\";

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
            var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential);

            // Testing connection
            Console.WriteLine("Testing connection to SharePoint...");
            var sites = await graphClient.Sites.GetAsync();

            if (sites != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Connected to SharePoint. Listing all active sites...");

                foreach (var site in sites.Value)
                {
                    if (site.WebUrl.Contains("sharepoint.com") && !site.WebUrl.Contains("personal"))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Site: {site.DisplayName}, URL: {site.WebUrl}, ID: {site.Id}");
                        string sitePath = Path.Combine(downloadPath, site.DisplayName ?? site.Id);
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(sitePath);

                        // Processing site contents
                        await ProcessSite(graphClient, site.Id, sitePath);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to connect to SharePoint or no sites found.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    static async Task ProcessSite(GraphServiceClient graphClient, string siteId, string path)
    {
        try
        {
            // Processing drives of the site
            await ProcessDrives(graphClient, siteId, path);

            // Retrieving subsites
            var subSites = await graphClient.Sites[siteId].Sites.GetAsync();
            if (subSites.Value != null && subSites.Value.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var subSite in subSites.Value)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Processing Sub-Site: {subSite.DisplayName}");
                    string subSitePath = Path.Combine(path, subSite.DisplayName ?? subSite.Id);
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(subSitePath);

                    // Recursively processing subsites
                    await ProcessSite(graphClient, subSite.Id, subSitePath);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error processing site with ID {siteId}: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    static async Task ProcessDrives(GraphServiceClient graphClient, string siteId, string path)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Processing drives for site with ID: {siteId}");

        var drives = await graphClient.Sites[siteId].Drives.GetAsync();
        if (drives.Value != null && drives.Value.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var drive in drives.Value)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Processing Drive: {drive.Name}");
                string drivePath = Path.Combine(path, drive.Name ?? string.Empty);
                Directory.CreateDirectory(drivePath);

                await ProcessDriveItems(graphClient, drive.Id, drivePath);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No drives found.");
        }
    }

    static async Task ProcessDriveItems(GraphServiceClient graphClient, string driveId, string path)
    {
        try
        {
            var rootItems = await graphClient.Drives[driveId].Root.GetAsync();
            if (rootItems.Folder != null)
            {
                var children = await graphClient.Drives[driveId].Items[rootItems.Id].Children.GetAsync();
                await ProcessItems(graphClient, driveId, children.Value, path);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error processing drive items: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    static async Task ProcessItems(GraphServiceClient graphClient, string driveId, IList<DriveItem> items, string path)
    {
        if (items != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                var itemPath = Path.Combine(path, item.Name ?? string.Empty);
                if (item.Folder != null) // It's a folder
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(itemPath);
                    var folderItems = await graphClient.Drives[driveId].Items[item.Id].Children.GetAsync();
                    await ProcessItems(graphClient, driveId, folderItems.Value, itemPath);
                }
                else if (item.File != null) // It's a file
                {
                    var fileContent = await graphClient.Drives[driveId].Items[item.Id].Content.GetAsync();
                    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(itemPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                    {
                        await fileContent.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine($"Downloaded {item.Name} to {itemPath}");

                    // Saving meta-information
                    var fileMetaInfo = new
                    {
                        item.Name,
                        item.CreatedDateTime,
                        item.LastModifiedDateTime,
                        CreatedBy = item.CreatedBy?.User?.DisplayName,
                        LastModifiedBy = item.LastModifiedBy?.User?.DisplayName
                    };
                    var metaInfoPath = $"{itemPath}.meta.json";
                    await File.WriteAllTextAsync(metaInfoPath, System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(fileMetaInfo));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


Troubleshooting Steps Taken:
Verified Site Settings: Downloaded and compared the XML settings of both (when I say both, I mean a working and a non-working) sites; found them to be structurally identical. Also downloaded the home.aspx files for them, also nearly no difference beside an ID.
Checked Permissions: Ensured that the permissions for both sites are the same. Even the same users have access to it, as in the admin-center, also as directly in SharePoint.
Listed All Lists: Verified that all lists exist on both sites.
Error Logging: Implemented detailed error logging to capture any issues during the backup process.
Issue Details:
The backup for most projects fails without providing a clear error message. (Files are just not downloaded)
The process fails during the retrieval or processing of drive items, but no specific error is captured in the logs.
**Request for Help: **
Any insights or suggestions on why the backup might be failing for the projects?
Are there any additional steps or debugging techniques that I should consider?
Could there be any hidden configurations or settings in SharePoint that I might be overlooking?
Thank you for your assistance!

You need to check the properties of graphClient to get a clue on what is wrong.  I suspect that some sites are using Windows Authentication while other are using OAUTH2 Authentication.  Other possibilities is there is more than one domain and you do not have access to all the domains.

Thanks for your input. There's just one domain, the authentication shouldn't matter, because I gain access with an application secret, straight from my app-registrations. I identified another issue which obv. affects all the sites: the non-working sites in SharePoint, there's a user-defined App running, which obv. prevent my application, to "see" these sites. I picked two sites and deleted this app, (it's just not needed anymore) and currently I have testrun, so - we will see if this helps. Thx for your hints. I'll check them again.

Why should the authentication not matter?  Your account may not have access rights to all sites.  Even if you gain access to the site you still may not have permission to the folders.  What I usually recommend trying in cases like this is to use a Windows Explorer and try manually to go to each site.  Use \servername and see if you can see any folders.  Then try going into the folders.  Try on a working site and then a non working site.  The windows explorer will give better error message to help solve issue.  If you are an admin use a dollar sign instead of the colon in the drive name.

The Application does not call sharepoint directly, it accesses it by Graph API, I am able to work on all sites (delete, create, manage)

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=csharp and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/auth-concepts   Use this for troubleshooting : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/find-mg-graph-permission?view=graph-powershell-1.0

Thanks for your hints. I followed the instructions you gave me some time before. The Graph-API has all neccessary access (even some more at the moment, I'll remove that if it's working) and I granted it as admin. Currently I am looking for configuration differences on the sites itself (working vs. non-working), maybe it's something like an incompatibility, because every new one I create is backed up.
